# Problema al usar un singleton con un abstract factory

Tags: c++, poo, c++11, patrones-de-diseño, c++98

Solo puse el titulo del patron que estoy usando, pero ese no es problema(quizas se a mi parecer un problema de header) igualmente trate de detallar todo en mi codigo con sus respectivo error de compilacion. Si alguien tiene alguna idea de solucionarlo le agradeceria por la ayuda.

```
#ifndef SUPERMARKET_SUPERMARKET_H_
#define SUPERMARKET_SUPERMARKET_H_

#include "CountryFactory.h"

class Supermarket {
private:
    Menu *menu;
    Ticket *ticket;
public:
    Supermarket();
    void vender();
    virtual ~Supermarket();
};

#endif
```

```
#include "Supermarket.h"

Supermarket::Supermarket() {
    ticket = CountryFactory::getInstance()->createTicket();
    menu = CountryFactory::getInstance()->createMenu();
}

void Supermarket::vender() {
    bool terminado = false;

    do {
        menu->execute(ticket);
    }while (!terminado);
}

Supermarket::~Supermarket() {
    delete ticket;
    delete menu;
}
```

Aplicando abstract Factory con singleton

```
#ifndef SUPERMARKET_COUNTRYFACTORY_H_
#define SUPERMARKET_COUNTRYFACTORY_H_

#include "Menu.h"
#include "Ticket.h"

class CountryFactory {
protected:
    CountryFactory();
    static CountryFactory* instance;
public:
    static CountryFactory* getInstance();
    virtual Menu* createMenu();
    virtual Ticket* createTicket();
    virtual ~CountryFactory();
};

#endif
```

Aqui no se como eliminar un singleton con el destructor sin que me de un bucle infinito

```
#include "CountryFactory.h"
#include "SpanishFactory.h"


CountryFactory* CountryFactory::instance = nullptr;

CountryFactory::CountryFactory() {
}

CountryFactory* CountryFactory::getInstance() {
    if(instance){
        instance = new SpanishFactory();
    }
    return instance;
}

CountryFactory::~CountryFactory() {
}
```

Aqui es donde me salta el problema, que creo que un tema de header.

```
#ifndef SUPERMARKET_COUNTRYFACTORY_H_
#define SUPERMARKET_COUNTRYFACTORY_H_

#include "CountryFactory.h"

class SpanishFactory : public CountryFactory{
public:
    explicit SpanishFactory();
    Menu* createMenu() override;
    Ticket* createTicket() override;
    virtual ~SpanishFactory();
};

#endif
```

member declaration not found(en cada uno)

```
SpanishFactory::SpanishFactory() : CountryFactory() {
}

Menu* SpanishFactory::createMenu() {
    return new Menu();
}

Ticket* SpanishFactory::createTicket() {
    return new Ticket();
}

SpanishFactory::~SpanishFactory() {
}
```

Tipo de error al compilar:

```
20:49:16 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project supermarket ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/supermarket/CountryFactory.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/supermarket/CountryFactory.d" -MT"src/supermarket/CountryFactory.o" -o "src/supermarket/CountryFactory.o" "../src/supermarket/CountryFactory.cpp"
../src/supermarket/CountryFactory.cpp: In static member function ‘static CountryFactory* CountryFactory::getInstance()’:
../src/supermarket/CountryFactory.cpp:12:18: error: expected type-specifier before ‘SpanishFactory’
   instance = new SpanishFactory();
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [src/supermarket/CountryFactory.o] Error 1
src/supermarket/subdir.mk:33: recipe for target 'src/supermarket/CountryFactory.o' failed

20:49:17 Build Finished (took 637ms)
```

Comment: ¿ Me parece a mi, o has puesto en todos tus archivos el miso `#define SUPERMARKET_COUNTRYFACTORY_H_` ?

Comment: SUPERMARKET_COUNTRYFACTORY_H_ es lo que estaba en este codigo cuando los escribi, pero antes estaba con SUPERMARKET_SPANISH_FACTORY_H_ (para la clase SpanishFactory)y tambien tenia una clase FreanchFactory (con si #define SUPERMARKET_FRENCH_FACTORY_H_) igualmente me tiraba error.

Answer (score 1):

Como te indican en los comentarios, estás usando la misma guarda en dos cabeceras diferentes. Eso hace que el compilador no cargue la cabecera de `SpanishFactory` y por eso no es capaz de encontrar el constructor de dicha factoría.

Modifica las guardas para que sean diferentes:

```
#ifndef SUPERMARKET_SPANISHFACTORY_H_
//                  ~~~~~~~

#define SUPERMARKET_SPANISHFACTORY_H_
//                  ~~~~~~~

#include "CountryFactory.h"

class SpanishFactory : public CountryFactory{

// ...
```

Comment: Hola ya lo intente tambien de esa manera, porque tenia otra clase llamada: FrenchFactory con su #define SUPERMARKET_FRENCHFACTORY_H_ por eso me fui por esta segunda manera.